# How to query a mongo collection to return the full document with virtual fields containing calculated values from the sub-document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to query a collection for a specific document that contains a sub-document. The sub-document contains values for which I'd like to obtain
the highest and lowest scores from that sub-document and return that result as virtual fields to the original document.

I have the following dataset:

```js
{
"_id" : "d0e78492342f9f-f843ec7-4bd14g3h-bh34j3a9-02d6ah32k8e6b79e",
"name" : "Addison Hunt",
"tests" : [
    {
        "name"  : "lorem",
        "score" : 79
    },
    {
        "name"  : "vallum",
        "score" : 100
    },
    {
        "name"  : "ipsum",
        "score" : 65
    }
],
"created_at" : 1401488865684,
"class" : "dolor sit amit",
"user_id" : "005G5635231325O4VIAU"
```

}

In mongo 2.4, how can I query mongo once to return the following result:

```js
{
    "_id" : "d0e78492342f9f-f843ec7-4bd14g3h-bh34j3a9-02d6ah32k8e6b79e",
    "name" : "Addison Hunt",
    "tests" : [
        {
            "name"  : "lorem",
            "score" : 79
        },
        {
            "name"  : "vallum",
            "score" : 100
        },
        {
            "name"  : "ipsum",
            "score" : 65
        }
    ],
    "created_at" : 1401488865684,
    "class" : "dolor sit amit",
    "user_id" : "005G5635231325O4VIAU",
    "worst_test": {
        "name"  : "ipsum",
        "score" : 65
    },
    "best_test": {
        "name"  : "vallum",
        "score" : 100
    }
}
```

Where "best_test" and "worst_test" are virtual fields representing the tests with the highest and lowest scores, respectively.
I've tried with many different ways and the closest I've gotten is with this query:

```js
db.students.aggregate([
    { $match: { 
        '_id': 'd0e78492342f9f-f843ec7-4bd14g3h-bh34j3a9-02d6ah32k8e6b79e'
    }},
    { $unwind: '$tests' },
    { $sort: {'tests.score': 1} },
    { $group: { 
        _id: '$_id',
        student_tests: {$push: "$$ROOT"},
        worst_test: {$first: '$tests'},
        best_test: { $last: '$tests' } 
    }}
]);
```

Which yields this result:

```js
{
"_id" : "d0e78492342f9f-f843ec7-4bd14g3h-bh34j3a9-02d6ah32k8e6b79e",
"student_tests" : [
    {
        "name" : "Addison Hunt",
        "tests" : [
            {
                "name"  : "ipsum",
                "score" : 65
            }
        ],
        "created_at" : 1401488865684,
        "class" : "dolor sit amit",
        "user_id" : "005G5635231325O4VIAU",
    },
    {
        "name" : "Addison Hunt",
        "tests" : [
            {
                "name"  : "lorem",
                "score" : 79
            }
        ],
        "created_at" : 1401488865684,
        "class" : "dolor sit amit",
        "user_id" : "005G5635231325O4VIAU",
    },
    {
        "name" : "Addison Hunt",
        "tests" : [
            {
                "name"  : "vallum",
                "score" : 100
            }
        ],
        "created_at" : 1401488865684,
        "class" : "dolor sit amit",
        "user_id" : "005G5635231325O4VIAU",
    },
],
"worst_test": {
    "name"  : "ipsum",
    "score" : 65
},
"best_test": {
    "name"  : "vallum",
    "score" : 100
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [**`$$ROOT`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) then in fact you are using MongoDB 2.6 as this is an aggregation variable only introduced in that version.

But while handy for various things, all it does is represent the entire document at the present stage of the pipeline where used. To do what you want and return the original document unmodified but with additional fields, you could use it in [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage before the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to assign to the `_id` field, but really you don't have *exactly* the same document as you would still need to `$project` at the end in order to get the correct document shape out of those elements.

You best bet is just projecting the fields, but keeping an un-altered copy of the array before any [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) is applied:

```js
db.students.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "_id": "d0e78492342f9f-f843ec7-4bd14g3h-bh34j3a9-02d6ah32k8e6b79e"
    }},
    { "$project": {
         "name": 1,
         "tests": 1,
         "created_at": 1,
         "class": 1,
         "user_id": 1,
         "testCopy": "$tests" 
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$testCopy" },
    { "$sort": { "testCopy.score": 1 } },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id: "$_id",
        "tests": { "$first": "$tests" },
        "created_at": { "$first": "$created_at" },
        "class": { "$first": "$class" },
        "user_id": { "$first": "$user_id" },
        "worst_test": { "$first": "$testCopy" },
        "best_test": { "$last": "$testCopy" } 
    }}
]);
```

Or using `$$ROOT` as mentioned before, alternately just placing the fields under the `_id` individually in the `$project`:

```js
db.students.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "_id": "d0e78492342f9f-f843ec7-4bd14g3h-bh34j3a9-02d6ah32k8e6b79e"
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": "$$ROOT",
        "tests": 1
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$tests" },
    { "$sort": { "tests.score": 1 } },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id",
        "aworst_test": { "$first": "$tests" },
        "abest_test": { "$last": "$tests" } 
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": "$_id._id",
        "tests": "$_id.tests",
        "created_at": "$_id.created_at",
        "class": "$_id.class",
        "user_id": "$_id.user_id",
        "worst_test": "$aworst_test",
        "best_test": "$abest_test"
    }}
]);
```

But as you see, you are still doing the `$project` work somewhere in order to get the structure you want, as well as the "renamed fields" to maintain the field order you want as the `$project` will otherwise "optimize" and "keep" any fields that have not been renamed and "append" new fields after the existing ones.

There really is no simple way to "get all fields" in the same way as you originally found them. Operations like `$project` and `$group` are an "all or nothing" affair, where they only explicitly produce what you tell them to.

Comment: Regarding the "all or nothing affair" with `$project` and `$group`, if your schema is known in the application layer, you could "render" each object into the aggregation pipeline rather than hard-coding the properties.

Comment: @zamnuts Well said and I glad you did. I have repeated the concept countless times already. MongoDB queries and aggregation queries are just data structures. So generate them, which is also easier to do than generating a declarative language such as SQL. Mention that in any answer and you immediately get my personal +1

Comment: @zamnuts Can you give an example of what you mean by "render each object into the aggregation pipeline rather than hard-coding the properties"?

Comment: @user3871070 What is meant there is that your application has some concept of "schema" where you actually define some form of structure that can be introspected in order to form queries like this. But there are always "rules" to this. This actually answers your question. If you want to know how to introspect a "schema" of sorts, then you really need to ask another question. StackOverflow has a **One** question only model for a very good reason.

Comment: @user3871070 Neil Lunn is correct, form a new question. But if you need some help on where to start as far as terminology and ideas, Mongoose is a great object modeler (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html).

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't mean to deviate to another topic; I just wanted clarification on what you meant about rendering the objects. You're Mongoose example helps makes sense of it now. Thanks. I'm testing the queries now.